# What is the song on the title screen of Dragon Ball Z: Resurrection 'F'?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-movies

There is a song from the title screen from *Resurrection F*. I think it is in the Bluray version, but I'm trying to figure out what the name is.

Does anybody know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The title song for Resurrection 'F' is: "Z no Chikai" (a.k.a "Pledge of Z") 
by Norihito Sumitomo.